# Python - Iterate and Alternate through two lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following two lists:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

ltrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I would like for the output to be:

```
1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, d, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

I have tried both:

```
for x in nums:
    for y in ltrs:
        print(x, Y)

for x, y in zip(nums, ltrs):
    print(x, y)
```

Neither produce the output I am looking for as the **ZIP method** provided as answer for other similar questions, **does not work in my case** because, as far as I know, ZIP does not work when the **lists are of different length**.

Comment: The answer provided for that question does not work in this case, as you can see I tried the 'zip' method - not what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Using `zip`, and `str()` for the numbers, build up a list of strings which alternate between the two, then print `', '.join(the_list)`

Comment: [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)